# cocoa-created PDF display in CMYK instead of RGB (with Acrobat)

Tags: objective-c, pdf-generation

Good morning,

I'm working on a PDF generator for a photo-book application and I encounter a color management problem for the preview in Acrobat. (I consider myself as a beginner in cocoa but I'm quite familiar with color management). There is the process I follow :

- create a NSView for double-pages (sheets) and draw content
- add this view to an offscreen window
- get PDF data of the view with dataWithPDFInsideRect
- create a NSPDFImageRep and add it to a empty NSImage
- create PDFPage with the image, set box sizes and insert it to a PDFDocument

All images and graphic elements are specified in RGB. (images have sRGB embedded profile).

Pdf looks fine in Apple preview.app, rasterize correctly in Photoshop. But when opened with Acrobat, I see it through a CMYK simulation (apparently). I can get the correct color aspect when I ask for a profile simulation with sRGB (or other RGB profile).

I have made several attempts to manipulate PDF metadatas, without success, I tried to make a very simple case (1 page - 1 image) with CGPDFContext, tried to set OutputIntents... I'm a bit lost, nothing seems to change the situation.

Note : PDF created (in RGB) with InDesign are displaying in RGB in Acrobat without any special setting. I would like my PDF to do the same...

Does anybody encounter the same problem ?
Thanks a lot for any precision or help !

You can download a (heavy...) PDF generated as explained here :
http://bunex-industries.com/filesToDownload/couverture.zip

Comment: Unless someone immediately has an answer, could you supply a sample PDF for inspection?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've edited my question with a link to a PDF

Answer (score 0):

I assume your PDF file contains some transparency (soft masks probably) and in this situation Adobe Acrobat switches to CMYK (nobody knows why, only Acrobat does this, other viewers work as expected). 
But an exact answer  can be given only if you can provide a sample PDF file.

UPDATE: The first page contains an extended graphics state that sets the fill alpha to 0 and this causes Acrobat to switch to CMYK. A solution is to add to the document an output intent with a RGB ICC colorspace.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I wasn't aware of that. (I've added a link in my first post)

Comment: Great, my problem is solved ! Thanks a lot for your time and expertise, i had indeed several hidden elements with alpha = 0 in my drawing function. Preview in Acrobat is now exactly as I need.